# JPA many to many constraint violation exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA to store data and faced two problems during implementation. I have two entities (Station and Commodity) that have many-to-many relationship with intermediate table so that I had to created the third one. When app receives message it converts its data to entites and should save but sometimes app throwing a `ConstraintViolationException` because there is null value at foreign key field referencing to Commodity entity.

I've tried simple approach: selecting needed commodity from database and saving it if there is no one. Then I started to use bulk searching all commodities of message and then putting it where are needed. None of them did a trick.

In my opinion the problem could be caused by multi-threading read\insert.

The second problem is that service stop running when exception is thrown. App can lost some of transactions that's not a big deal but it simply stops after rollback.

How can I resolve these conflicts?

Here is code of data handling class and diagram of entities :

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ZeromqCommoditiesServiceImpl implements ZeromqCommoditesService {
    private final CategoryTransactionHandler categoryHandler;
    private final CommodityTransactionHandler commodityHandler;
    private final EconomyTransactionHandler economyHandler;
    private final StationTransactionHandler stationHandler;
    private final SystemTransactionHandler systemHandler;

    @Override
    @Transactional(
        isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
        propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
        rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    @Modifying
    public void saveData(ZeromqCommodityPayload payload) {
        CommodityContent content = payload.getContent();
        var station = stationHandler.createOrFindStation(content.getStationName());
        var system = systemHandler.createOrFindSystem(content.getSystemName());
        var commodityReferences = getMapOfCommodities(content);
        station.setSystem(system);
        updateEconomies(station, content);
        updateProhibited(station, content, commodityReferences);
        updateStationCommodities(station, content, commodityReferences);
        try {
            saveStation(station);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException | PersistentObjectException | DataAccessException e) {
            log.error("Error saving commodity info \n" + content, e);
        }
    }

    public void saveStation(StationEntity station) {
        stationHandler.saveStation(station);
        if (station.getId() != null) {
            log.debug(String.format("Updated \"%s\" station info", station.getName()));
        } else {
            log.debug(String.format("Updated \"%s\" station info", station.getName()));
        }
    }

    private void updateEconomies(StationEntity station, CommodityContent content) {
        station.getEconomies().clear();
        if (content.getEconomies() != null) {
            var economies = content.getEconomies()
                .stream()
                .map(economy -> {
                    var stationEconomyEntity = economyHandler.createOrFindEconomy(economy.getName());
                    Double proportion = economy.getProportion();
                    stationEconomyEntity.setProportion(proportion != null ? proportion : 1.0);
                    return stationEconomyEntity;
                })
                .peek(economy -> economy.setStation(station))
                .toList();
            station.getEconomies().addAll(economies);
        }
    }

    private void updateProhibited(
        StationEntity station,
        CommodityContent content,
        Map<String, CommodityEntity> commodityEntityMap) {
        station.getProhibited().clear();
        if (content.getProhibited() != null) {
            var prohibitedCommodityEntities = content.getProhibited()
                .stream()
                .map(prohibited -> {
                        String eddnName = prohibited.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
                        CommodityEntity commodityReference = getCommodityEntity(commodityEntityMap, eddnName);
                        return new ProhibitedCommodityEntity(station, commodityReference);
                    }
                )
                .toList();
            station.getProhibited().addAll(prohibitedCommodityEntities);
        }
    }

    private void updateStationCommodities(
        StationEntity station,
        CommodityContent content,
        Map<String, CommodityEntity> commodityEntityMap) {
        station.getCommodities().clear();
        if (content.getCommodities() != null) {
            var commodities = content.getCommodities()
                .stream()
                .map(commodity -> {
                    CommodityEntity commodityReference = getCommodityEntity(
                        commodityEntityMap,
                        commodity.getEddnName());
                    return StationCommodityEntity.builder()
                        .commodity(commodityReference)
                        .buyPrice(commodity.getBuyPrice())
                        .sellPrice(commodity.getSellPrice())
                        .demand(commodity.getDemand())
                        .stock(commodity.getStock())
                        .station(station)
                        .build();
                })
                .toList();
            station.getCommodities().addAll(commodities);
        }
    }

    private CommodityEntity getCommodityEntity(Map<String, CommodityEntity> commodityEntityMap, String eddnName) {
        return commodityEntityMap.get(eddnName);
    }

    private Map<String, CommodityEntity> getMapOfCommodities(@NotNull CommodityContent content) {
        Set<String> commodities = content.getCommodities()
            .stream()
            .map(Commodity::getEddnName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        if (content.getProhibited() != null && content.getProhibited().size() > 0) {
            commodities.addAll(content.getProhibited().
                stream()
                .map(item -> item.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        }
        var commodityReferencesMap = commodityHandler.findAllByEddnName(commodities)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                CommodityEntity::getEddnName,
                item -> item
            ));

        commodities.forEach(commodity -> {
            if (commodityReferencesMap.get(commodity.toLowerCase()) == null) {
                CommodityCategoryEntity category = categoryHandler.createOrFindCategory("Unknown");
                CommodityEntity newCommodity = new CommodityEntity(commodity, commodity, category);
                CommodityEntity managedCommodity = commodityHandler.saveCommodity(newCommodity);

                commodityReferencesMap.put(managedCommodity.getEddnName(), managedCommodity);
            }
        });

        return commodityReferencesMap;
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are very separate problems with different causes and solutions- you should break them out separately.

Comment: For the ConstraintViolationException issue - why would the FK be null exactly? Do you expect the referenced object to exist in the database? What are you 'saving' and what is the mapping it has to this FK referenced object? How are you still getting issues if you read in the object from the DB and setting the reference using it in the same context? What about any existing station's StationCommodityEntity instances, or does this problem only occur on new StationEntity instances?

Comment: @Chris, the problem occurs when I try to find existing entries. Before service init there another service that loads commodities. So I 146% confident that commodity is present in db. I've annotated ```saveData``` method with ```@Lock``` and CommodityEntity with ```@Immutable``` so as FK to StationEntity and CommodityEntity at StationCommodityEntity. I wonder if it works but app is running for 5 hours and still no exception so far

Comment: I don't understand how lock or immutable would help - a null can only be set if the reference is null, which would mean something is wrong with your app. But it depends on the mapping and the actual error message - you really should show them in future questions.